# Matching file extensions - regex nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm currently running a regular expression in a node file that's designed to copy my custom fontello icon font files across to the public directory. To ensure I'm not copying irrelevant files I'm using the following:

```
var match = new RegExp(/\.(woff|svg|ttf|eot)/g);
if (match.test(fileName)) {
    // Do something
}
```

As I cycle through the fonts available, the only two that are being matched are

```
app.svg
app.eot
```

The `app.ttf` and `app.woff` files are ***not*** matching the expression.

I have tried out the expression over at http://www.regexr.com/ and it appears to work for my purposes. Keep in mind that I don't require much more stringent testing than this as there is only a handful of files in that directory.

If anybody can give me some guidance I would be most appreciative.

Comment: So the "m" modifier appears to have rectified this. I'm curious as to why. Thanks so much for giving me a hand with that.

Comment: I guess in the stream from the zip file they're possibly wrapping on multiple lines? Regardless, you're awesome! Thanks so much for that. Did you want to put it down below as an answer and I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct.Tried it.

[See](http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/5)

Comment: @jellis filename variable contains all the filenames or just 1 file?

Comment: Just the one filename (eg fileName = 'app.svg';)

Comment: @jellis for one file name m  modifier will not make any difference.Now i am curious too. are you sure filename is simple "app.svg" and nothing else?

Comment: I know, right? Well, it's just behaving oddly now. I wish I knew more. This has fixed my short-term issue... of course, my hatred for Node is now extreme and I'm moving my build script away from it to Phing.